# getByID and getByIndex are not working in react

Tags: reactjs, indexeddb

I have a problem with indexedDB in react. I have a database for saving parameters and must keep only one parameter daily for each user. So I decided to set a `dateAndId` for a key of the database. Schema of my DB:

```
    {
      store: "dataTime",
      storeConfig: { keyPath: "dateAndId", autoIncrement: false},
      storeSchema: [
        { name: "parameters", keypath: "parameters", options: { unique: false } },
      ],
    }
```

I have no problem with the `update` function. I update the database with the below code. It's finding its corresponding object and updates it.

```
update({
      dateAndId: currentDate + '-' + UserInfo.id,
      parameters: {
        ...UserInfo.parameters,
      },
    }).then(
      (event) => {
        console.log("timeData updated: ", event);
      }
    );
```

But when I use `getByID` and `getByIndex`, errors pop up and say: I can't find corresponding object

for example for `getByIndex` I get
[image]

and when I use `getByID` I get
[image]

While I'm sure the parameter is a valid key because it is a string.

It is my code of `getByID`:

```
useEffect(() => {
    getByID(String(currentDate + '-' + UserInfo.id)).then(data => {
      UserInfo.setParameters(data);
      });
  }, []);
```

What do you think is the exact problem? I think it is simple but I can't see it.

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Id wasn't Integer. It was String so indexedDB can't handle that